# Get data from geoapi into google spreadsheets

Tags: xml, google-sheets, geoapi

I'm trying to get country name given the city, here's my formula for Warszawa:
    =importxml("http://api.geonames.org/search?q=warszawa&maxRows=1&style=FULL&username=glebvk";"/geonames/geoname[1]/Countrycode")

I get `"Error: Imported content is empty."`

Answer (score 1):

Change your XPath query from `/geonames/geoname[1]/Countrycode` to `/geonames/geoname[1]/countryCode`. XPath queries are case-sensitive.